# How to cancel a flowret pipeline from outside

Tags: java

I have a linear flowret pipeline which does a series of job one by one.

I would like to implement a cancellation functionality that allows the user to cancel the pipeline by issuing a cancel command.

What is the proper way to do this?

I am thinking to set a boolean variable in the context variable. At the beginning of every step, I just check the variable and see if the pipeline is cancelled.

However, I don't know how to get access to the context variable from outside the flowret the pipeline.

Can someone give some suggestions?